# How to test any method invokation for throwing an exception?

Tags: java, exception, junit

JUnit 4.12

I have the following utility method:

```
public class StaticFieldsUtils {

    public static <T> T getPublicStaticFieldByName(String name, Class<T> clazz){
        for(Field f : clazz.getDeclaredFields()){
            if(Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers()) && 
                 Modifier.isPublic(f.getModifiers()) && 
                 f.getName().equals(name))
                try {
                    Object fieldValue = f.get(null); 
                    if(clazz.isAssignableFrom(fieldValue.getClass()))
                        return (T) fieldValue;
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) { 
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Invalid access to the field %s", name));
                }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("A public field with the name %s does not exist in the class %s", name, clazz.getSimpleName()));
    }

    //Some other utility methods
}
```

Now, I need to write test-cases that checked that the `IllegalArgumetnException` is thrown only if there's no public static field of the same type or one of its subtypes.

Here is what I tend to write:

```
public class StaticFieldsUtilsTest {

    private static class StaticFieldContainer{
        public static final StaticFieldContainer FIELD1 = new StaticFieldContainer();
        public static final StaticFieldContainer FIELD2 = new StaticFieldContainer();
        public static final StaticFieldContainer FIELD3 = new StaticFieldContainer();
        public static final StaticFieldContainer FIELD4 = new StaticFieldContainer();
        protected static final StaticFieldContainer FIELD5 = new StaticFieldContainer();
        static final StaticFieldContainer FIELD6 = new StaticFieldContainer();
        private static final StaticFieldContainer FIELD7 = new StaticFieldContainer();
        public static StaticFieldContainer FIELD8 = new StaticFieldContainer();
    }

    @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testViolations(){
        StaticFieldContainer field = StaticFieldsUtils.getPublicStaticFieldByName("FIELD5", StaticFieldContainer.class); 
    }

    @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testViolations2(){
        StaticFieldContainer field = StaticFieldsUtils.getPublicStaticFieldByName("FIELD6", StaticFieldContainer.class); 
    }
    //ETC
}
```

The issue is I can't reliably put more than one the method invocations in the single method `@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class) public void testViolationsX()` because I need to check that ***each*** invocation throws.

***QUESTION:*** Is there some `JUnit` factility to avoid writing a single method for any such invocation to check if it throws?

Comment: What do you want to test? Your utils class or the StaticFieldContainer? If it's the first one, then the second test is obsolete.

Comment: @Tom Well, I thought that StaticFieldContainer being a `private static class` of the Test class makes it clear that it's just for testing the utils class. Couldn't you clarify why it is obsolete?

Comment: Why do you think you need to test this specific feature twice? Are you afraid that the first test could pass by luck? If you want to test if your class can also read package-private variable, then yes you need to test it in a second method with a much better test method name.

Comment: @Tom Because FIELD6 and FIELD5 have different access modifiers. Therefore I thought it was a different test-case.

Comment: It is, so why do you want to test them in one method? Because you like to find out which of them failed first (your test won't tell you that) or because you like to test different features in the same test method? Please mind this general "rule": one test per method with a proper method names which tells what it tests there. If one then fails you would exactly know which feature failed and what it tried to do.

Comment: @Tom Ah, probably I understood your point. So it's much better to create two test methods with names e.g. `@Test testProtectedAccessFail()` and `@Test testDefaultAccessFail()` instead of on `@Test testAll()`, right?

Comment: Yes it is. Let's assume your one method of your question failes, you would get an failure like "method xyz should have thrown 'IAException'... " (depends a bit one the test framework). So you can't see if field 5 or 6 failed and what you've tried to check there. You would need to recheck the test code for this. A proper test with a proper name can tell you all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JUnit Theories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Theories) and the `ExpectedException` rule:

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class StaticFieldsUtilsTest {

  //your inner class with static fields


  @Rule
  public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

  @DataPoint
  public static String FIELD1 = "Field1";
  @DataPoint
  public static String FIELD2 = "Field2";

  @Theory
  public void testViolations(String field){
    thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    StaticFieldsUtils.getPublicStaticFieldByName(field, StaticFieldContainer.class); 
  }
}
```

If you want to apply many theories with other names, I recommend to create a custom annotation and a `ParameterSupplier` as explained [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Theories).

Comment: Thanks much, interesting point. Does it work fine if the test class contains a simple `@Test` methods? I mean, marking it with the annotation `@RunWith(Theories.class)` has no effect them, doesn't it?

Comment: I would separate the batch and the single tests from each other. If you insist to use `@Test` and `@Theory` in one class than try it and report success or failure.

Comment: Tried, for my simeple class containing the following test methods: `@Test public void test()` then goes `@Theory public void testFieldByNameViolations(String fieldName)` and then `@Theory
 public void testFieldByNameViolations(StaticFieldContainer staticField)` it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use also use a plain old for loop:

```
public void testViolations(){
    for (String fieldName : Arrays.asList("FIELD5", "FIELD6")) {
        try {
            StaticFieldContainer field = StaticFieldsUtils.getPublicStaticFieldByName(fieldName, StaticFieldContainer.class);
            fail();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }
    }
}
```